# <img/> and <span> do not align together using display flex

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

I am still new to CSS and wish to ask questions related to styled components of react. I am using display flex to make the <img> and <span> align on the same line, but it fail to do so.

```
<SignInGg><img src='images/google.svg' alt=''/><span>Sign in with Google</span></SignInGg>
```

```
const SignInGg = styled.a`
    font-weight: 600;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 15px 0;
    width: 35%;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 29px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: flex;
    & img {
        width: 30px;
        height: auto;
    }
    &:hover {
        border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
`;
```

The yellow highlights are the img and span components

[image]

Display flex is not working to make 2 things on the smae line

Comment: display:flex; align-item:center; justify-content:center; try to add this also.

Comment: @ShilpeSaxena the words Sign in with Google do become centered but the img does not have any responses

Comment: try to give some selector like class to img and then use that class name for styling property.

Comment: @ShilpeSaxena i added the className to img but still there is no response

Comment: Maybe some parent component has some styling that prevents img from vertical  centering, to test give img 
max-height: 100%;
 or max-height: 40px; just to test

Comment: @ЕмилЦоков omg thanks a lot, juz fount out some parent component stylling causing this issue, and have resolved it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set the image `display` and `position` properties, could you try this?

```
<SignInGg><img src='images/google.svg' alt=''/><span>Sign in with Google</span></SignInGg>

const SignInGg = styled.a`
    font-weight: 600;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 15px 0;
    width: 35%;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 29px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; // <- changed here
    align-items: center; // <- changed here
    justify-content: center; // <- changed here
    & img {
        width: 30px; 
        height: 30px; // <- changed here
        position: relative; // <- changed here
        display: inline-block; // <- changed here
    }
    &:hover {
        border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
`;
```

Comment: in this case, position relative do help to move the img to somewhere nearby the words 'Sign in with Google', but I still wondering why display flex does not work

Comment: also, if i use position relative and bottom 0px , the img logo and the words will place in the same line and work fine

Comment: @weston happy you fixed it :)